# Почему wp работает через раз

Tags: mysql, wordpress

То сайт нормально грузит, то выдает ошибку 
**Error establishing a database connection**

Причем, даже если перенести эту базу на другой сервер и другую **db**, то это не решает проблему.

Что это может быть, где искать проблему, как исправить?

Comment: "поучим wp" - отличный заголовок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На этом сайте разжёвано по мелочи эта ошибка: https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-ispravit-establishing-a-database-connection-wordpress/